# How to remove all files that were created n minutes ago in linux

Tags: linux, find

I guess in most cases, when extracting a tar archive, we will get a directory with the same name as the archive file but different suffix. But in some unlucky case, as I met today, after extracting a tarball, I find lots of files spread in the working directory, which is a nuisance.

So what I want to learn from you is that - how can I move those newly created files?  I know it should be some "find plus rm" fancy approach there, but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 39):

I wonder what `man find` would say. Then you can even show your efforts.

```
find . -type f -cmin -1
find . -type f -cmin -1 -delete
```

- The `-type f` is used to specify only regular files are selected.
- The `-cmin -1` the file's status was last changed in less than the past (one) minute.
- The `-delete` flag tells find to deletes all your electronics files in the known universe or something like that, so use caution when using it.

First doing a test run **without** the `-delete` flag is strongly recommended.

Note `-delete` is a non-portable extension.

I recommend reading the `find` manpage before using this, because it covers various gotchas and warnings that may apply in your situation.

Comment: Nice! -delete looks easier than -exec rm {} \;

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain the option choices

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -mtime -60s -exec mv {} /dest/dir \;
```

Finds every file in the current directory (and sub directories) that has been modified in the last 60 seconds and move them to /dest/dir.

Comment: Careful, extracted archives files may preserve original modification date. Best to use creation time.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu great point.

Answer (score 0):

The easies way (provided you don't have graphical interface) will be to use [mc](http://www.midnight-commander.org/). It can sort files by date.

You can also delete the files which were in the tar from command line:

```
> rm $( tar -ztf mytar.tar.gz )
```

(-ztf) is for tar.gz files. You can use (-tf) for normal tars, or (-jtf) for tar.bz2 files.

If the list of the files is too big, and the above command chokes, you can use xargs:

```
> tar -ztf mytar.tar.gz | xargs rm
```

Comment: wow, my bad - I did not read the question really - you need to move them, not delete (pls, fix the title, its misleading). I guess you still can delete them, then create a new dir, and untar there :). After all, move = copy + delete.